# model uncertainty dependent on time

Tags: regression, time-series, uncertainty

I have a very simple model to predict the variable $y$ at any time $t>0$.
The model is $$y = x$$ where $x$ is the most recent value recorded for $y$ at any time $t<0$.
The model is quite accurate for values of $x$ recorded close to $t=0$, while it performs worse for $t<<0$. I'd like to include this information in my model in the following way:
$$y = x + ε(t)$$
where $ε$ represents the error and $t$ the time passed after $x$ was recorded.
My goal would be to have for a model with a confidence interval looking like this:
[image]
However I am not sure how to fit this type of model and I can't find any literature using a similar method. Any help or suggestion would be strongly appreciated!

Comment: what's the purpose of your model?

Comment: anyway, there is plenty of models like yours. simplest I know is a ramdom walk, of any kind.

Comment: or a wiener process if time is considered as continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Gaussian Process

Consider using a [Gaussian Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) with a linear kernel. The picture below illustrates GP predictions with different kernels, and I think the linear case corresponds to your scenario quite well:
[image: gp on linear data]

The picture comes from [this blog post](http://sashagusev.github.io/2016-01/GP.html).

#### Bayesian linear regression

Another possibility, a typical output from a bayesian regression is the following picture:

[image: bayes lin reg]

It encodes the uncertainty about the parameters (and thus the regression line) as a function of the points already seen.

Comment: neither of the models you propose respect the first required property

Comment: I must correct myself, brownian gaussian process is perfect actually.

Comment: Does frequentist linear regression not have the same (or similar) property as the Bayesian linear regression? If so, you could drop "Bayesian". In any case, linear regression as illustrated here does not seem to provide a relevant solution.